# Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly #ERROR2002

Tags: mysql

server says that is not responding. Here is the ini.cnf

> 2017-04-17 15:29:55 358c InnoDB: Warning: Using
>   innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be
>   removed in future releases, together with the option
>   innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>   2017-04-17 15:29:55 13708 [Note] InnoDB:
>   innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of
>   small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool
>   at least up to 20MB.
>
> 2017-04-17 15:29:55 13708 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count
>   buffer pool pages 2017-04-17 15:29:55 13708 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB
>   memory heap is disabled 2017-04-17 15:29:55 13708 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions 2017-04-17
>   15:29:55 13708 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used
>   for memory barrier 2017-04-17 15:29:55 13708 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed
>   tables use zlib 1.2.3 2017-04-17 15:29:55 13708 [Note] InnoDB: Using
>   generic crc32 instructions 2017-04-17 15:29:55 13708 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M 2017-04-17 15:29:55 13708
>   [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 2017-04-17
>   15:29:55 13708 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is
>   Barracuda. 2017-04-17 15:29:55 13708 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback
>   segment(s) are active. 2017-04-17 15:29:55 13708 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Waiting for purge to start 2017-04-17 15:29:55 13708 [Note] InnoDB: 
>   Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.34-79.1 started; log
>   sequence number 1600716 2017-04-17 15:29:55 14108 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started 2017-04-17 15:29:55 13708
>   [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled. 2017-04-17 15:29:55 13708
>   [ERROR] c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: unknown variable
>   'master-user=root' 2017-04-17 15:29:55 13708 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: It looks like you are attempting to do master replication or master/slave set up and you have put some variables (probably in `my.ini`) that don't belong there. Remove those `master-*` variables from your `my.ini` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Does reinstall solve the solution?

Comment: It may. It's odd if this is a clean install that those would be in there. It'd probably just be easier to remove those variables from your `my.ini` and restart though.

Comment: Ok its fine now, Thanks i reinstalled that.